# How to overvrite maxColWidth in HeaderResize?

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.2

There is a value in Ext.grid.plugin.HeaderResize set to 1000.

It prevents pulling the column larger.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed in app.js (Ext.application) the following code

```
        Ext.require('Ext.grid.plugin.HeaderResizer', function() {
        Ext.grid.plugin.HeaderResizer.prototype.maxColWidth = 2000;
    });
```

This worked for me.